# Will I lose Microsoft Office?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

I had to restore my laptop to factory settings.  Now my laptop is saying I don't have space and asking if I want to delete my previous version of Windows.  If and when my previous version of Windows is deleted, will I lose Microsoft Office?

Answer (score 0):

You will not lose Microsoft Office by deleting the old files of Windows, although I would make sure you have the Office license key written down.

Answer (score 0):

If your office is a preinstalled version, Office will still exist after restoring factory settings.

If your office is manually downloaded by yourself, you will lose office on your device after you restore factory settings.

In addition, you all need to reactivate Office after you have factory settings. If your office is a bulk-activated version, you need to keep key. If your office is an Office 365 or retail version, you need to remember the active account number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will lose Office, and all of your other applications and personal data files.

So, before you re-install Windows, do a full image copy backup of your current situation. That way you will be able to recover any missing files. Make sure you can extract individual files from the backup.

Also, before doing the Windows re-install, use one of these tools to extract the 25-character Product Key(s) from the HD. It would be a good idea to print a copy of the report and save it to a USB.  You should also confirm that you have all of the required installation files for the other programs you want to re-install after re-installing windows.